# Rails 5 API custom authentication: 'skip_before_action' on GET routes

Tags: ruby, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

I've used [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-two) series as a starting point for a Rails backend for a work portfolio website. Adapting it has been mostly straightforward, and it's doing what I want it to. The one big problem is that the 'index' and 'show' (read actions) should be available without authentication, while 'create', 'update', and 'delete' (write actions) should require a valid JWT.

Following the approach used to exclude the signup and login routes from authentication, I've tried

```
skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: [:index, :show]
```

in the appropriate controller. This will however crash the application, with

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `works' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/works_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

While the problem seems apparent - if skipping the authentication action the class doesn't get instantiated - the fix isn't, to me at least. Could anyone please help?

The code for the project is [here](https://git.brnrds.com/brnrds/brnrds-server).

**Application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Response
  include ExceptionHandler

  # called before every action on controllers
  before_action :authorize_request
  attr_reader :current_user

  private

  # Check for valid request token and return user
  def authorize_request
    @current_user = (AuthorizeApiRequest.new(request.headers).call)[:user]
  end
end
```

**'Works' controller**

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController

  #skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: [:index, :show]

  before_action :set_work, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /works
  def index
    @works = current_user.works
    json_response(@works)
  end

  # POST /works
  def create
    @work = current_user.works.create!(work_params)
    json_response(@work, :created)
  end

  # GET /works/:id
  def show
    json_response(@work)
  end

  # PUT /works/:id
  def update
    @work.update(work_params)
    head :no_content
  end

  # DELETE /works/:id
  def destroy
    @work.destroy
    head :no_content
  end

  private

  def work_params
    # whitelist params
    params.permit(:title, :nature, :role, :client, :timeframe, :description, :images, :url, :blog_post)
  end

  def set_work
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**'Users' controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: :create

  def create
    user = User.create!(user_params)
    auth_token = AuthenticateUser.new(user.username, user.password).call
    response = { message: Message.account_created, access_token: auth_token }
    json_response(response, :created)
  end

  def show
    json_response(username: current_user.username)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.permit(
      :username,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation
    )
  end
end
```

**'Authentication' controller**

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: :authenticate

  # return auth token once user is authenticated
  def authenticate
    auth_token =
      AuthenticateUser.new(auth_params[:username], auth_params[:password]).call
    json_response(access_token: auth_token)
  end

  private

  def auth_params
    params.permit(:username, :password)
  end
end
```

**'AuthenticateUser' helper**

```
class AuthenticateUser
  def initialize(username, password)
    @username = username
    @password = password
  end

  # Service entry point
  def call
    JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
  end

  private

  attr_reader :username, :password

  # verify user credentials
  def user
    user = User.find_by(username: username)
    return user if user && user.authenticate(password)
    # raise Authentication error if credentials are invalid
    raise(ExceptionHandler::AuthenticationError, Message.invalid_credentials)
  end
end
```

**'AuthorizeApiRequest' helper**

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
  def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
  end

  # Service entry point - return valid user object
  def call
    {
      user: user
    }
  end

  private

  attr_reader :headers

  def user
    # check if user is in the database
    # memoize user object
    @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
    # handle user not found
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    # raise custom error
    raise(
      ExceptionHandler::InvalidToken,
      ("#{Message.invalid_token} #{e.message}")
    )
  end

  # decode authentication token
  def decoded_auth_token
    @decoded_auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
  end

  # check for token in `Authorization` header
  def http_auth_header
    if headers['Authorization'].present?
      return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
    end
      raise(ExceptionHandler::MissingToken, Message.missing_token)
  end
end
```

**'ExceptionHandler' helper**

```
module ExceptionHandler
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Define custom error subclasses - rescue catches `StandardErrors`
  class AuthenticationError < StandardError; end
  class MissingToken < StandardError; end
  class InvalidToken < StandardError; end

  included do
    # Define custom handlers
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :four_twenty_two
    rescue_from ExceptionHandler::AuthenticationError, with: :unauthorized_request
    rescue_from ExceptionHandler::MissingToken, with: :four_twenty_two
    rescue_from ExceptionHandler::InvalidToken, with: :four_twenty_two

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
      json_response({ message: e.message }, :not_found)
    end
  end

  private

  # JSON response with message; Status code 422 - unprocessable entity
  def four_twenty_two(e)
    json_response({ message: e.message }, :unprocessable_entity)
  end

  # JSON response with message; Status code 401 - Unauthorized
  def unauthorized_request(e)
    json_response({ message: e.message }, :unauthorized)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message states:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `works' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/works_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

Or to translate that, on line 10 of the works_controller.rb file, we're calling a method called `works` on `nil`, which is throwing an error.

Assuming line 10 of the works_controller is

```
@works = current_user.works
```

Then the error message is telling us that we're calling `works` on nil, i.e. we have no `current_user`.

Either where you assign this code is not working properly, or you're accessing this part of the code without signing in and haven't coded around that. Either way, the `current_user` variable is returning nil and shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I thought that would be the problem, `current user` is defined in ApplicationController and requires `AuthorizeApiRequest`. What I don't know is how to code around that while otherwise preserving the integrity of the authentication mechanism for the write actions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe an application wide helper that returns the current_user?

Comment: That's already in place, the problem is that right now all calls to current_user at authenticated. One possible solution would be to conditionally authenticate the user depending on what http verbs are used, i.e. skip authentication for GET, and authenticate for everything else. The problem is solved for now, by loading all works inside the index method, and fetching by id inside the show method. Will leave question for now in case someone proposes a cleaner way of doing things, or I learn one myself. Thanks for the input.